# how generator.next is causing an exception in this code

Tags: javascript, generator

Having difficulty understanding this code.

```
function* gen() {
  try {
    let result = yield "2 + 2 = ?"; // (1)

    alert("The execution does not reach here, because the exception is thrown above");
  } catch(e) {
    alert(e); // shows the error
  }
}

let generator = gen();

let question = generator.next().value; 

generator.throw(new Error("The answer is not found in my database")); // (2)
```

how this line (`let question = generator.next().value;`) influences the code, i mean generators only return yeilded values?

what does the author mean by (1) on the third line

Comment: Given how generators work, the author probably wants to guide the reader about the order of execution of this piece of code. Have you tried running it?

Comment: yes @Yoshi but i can't understand why or how it's throwing exception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following statement

```
generator.next()
```

will yield the following object:

```
{
   value: "2 + 2 = ?",
   done: false
}
```

At this point, generator function is paused at current yield which is

```
let result = yield "2 + 2 = ?";
```

If you call `generator.next()` and pass any argument to the `next()` method, that argument will become the value of the `yield` expression and will be assigned to the `result` variable.

But instead of calling `next()`, you have called `throw` method which is like injecting a `throw` statement where the current `yield` is, i.e. at line (1).

Calling `throw()` throws an exception inside the `try` block which is then caught by the `catch` block.

`throw` method returns an object which, in your case, is:

```
{
  value: undefined,
  done: true
}
```

`value` is undefined because you didn't return or yield any value from the `catch` block.

For more details, see: [MDN - Generator.prototype.throw()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator/throw)

> what does the author mean by (1) on the third line

Author is probably trying to communicate that the generator function will pause at (1); after that calling the `throw()` method will throw an error inside the `try` block as if there was a `throw` statement at (1) which is then caught by the `catch` block; `catch` block then logs the error on the console.